# Searching a web element using XPath though element attribute doesn't have any value

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I want to find below web element using selenium.

```
<div id type="screen">
<div id="abc" type="screen">
```

Here I want to find the first web element using XPath.

e.g. `By.XPath(".//div[not(contains(@id='')) and type='screen'");`

Using the above, I am not able to find the element.

Comment: Web element looks like this

Comment: <div id type="screen"/>
<div id="abc" type="screen"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you want to match this element, `<div id type="screen">`, which can be done using the following XPath:

```
.//div[@id='' and @type='screen']
```

In your XPath, you have an extraneous `not(contains())` call when selecting the `id`; you can simply select an empty (`''`) `id`. You have also forgotten to include the `@` before `type` and the closing bracket `]`.

Comment: Actually I wrote XPath similar like yours in my implemention. But it is not working probably because id attribute doesn't have any value not even empty string

Comment: Your XPath has syntax errors, did you try testing if my solution works?

Comment: @MahendraChoudhary This works for me `//*[@id="" and @type="screen"]`. Note that I've used double quotes.

Comment: @CanisMajoris It works, however I prefer being more verbose with my XPaths, so I dislike using wildcard (`*`) matching. Also, single quotes are preferred, if you use double quotes, you'll need to escape them which can get ugly: `By.XPath("//*[@id=\"\" and @type=\"screen\"]")`

Comment: @budi For me it doesn't work with single quotes. Besides escaping the double quotes depends on the programming language. With PHP it would be like `WebDriverBy::xpath('//*[@id="" and @type="screen"]')`

Comment: @CanisMajoris interesting... and yup I saw that the context of this problem was C#/Selenium, so I should've stated that it does depend on the language in my previous comment, thanks for clarifying!